# Trouble with data reader

Tags: c#, exception, datareader, oledbdatareader

Afternoon, I am writing a database management program to make things easier at work. I'm having trouble with the datareader if the table returns no results. I have searched all over the web for a solution but to no avail. So I am eating humble pie and asking.

Firstly so you understand the DB layout, we have multiple tables and I want to display the results in one list view. The code works fine for displaying the whole table but when trying to search is no result is found in the first table then it throws an exception for every table within the loop. But if the result is found in the first table it will continue to loop again until the search string is not found in each table.

Here is the code

```
private string _strDBPath;
private string _strContractNumber;
public string[] dbTables = new string[9] {"0", "1800", "2800", "4000", "5000", "5400", "5700", "6800", "7800"};
public string[] dbFields = new string[3] { "ContractNumber", "Name", "REF",};
private enum sqlType {Normal, Search}
private bool dbSearch =false;



private void frmRecords_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        lstContractsAddColums();
        timerStart.Start();
    }

    private void lstContractsAddColums()
    {
        lstContracts.Columns.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < dbFields.Length; i++) //Check to see if last field in array
            lstContracts.Columns.Add(dbFields[i], 200, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    }

    private void timerStart_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dbTables.Length; i++)
        {
            while (!dbSearch == false)
            {

            }
            dbGetData(i, sqlType.Search, "1000", "ContractNumber");
            dbSearch = false;
        }

        timerStart.Stop();
    }

    private void dbGetData(int dbTable, sqlType sqlRecords, string strSearch, string strField)
    {


        string mySQL = "SELECT ";

        for (int i = 0; i < dbFields.Length; i++) //Check to see if last field in array
            if (i < dbFields.Length - 1)
            {
                mySQL = mySQL + dbFields[i] + ", "; //This is not the last field
            }
            else
            {
                mySQL = mySQL + dbFields[i] + " "; //This is the last field (No commor required)
            }

        switch (sqlRecords)
        {
            case sqlType.Normal:
                mySQL = mySQL + " From " + dbTables[dbTable] + " ORDER BY ContractNumber"; //Adds the last part of the sayntex           
            break;

            case sqlType.Search:
                mySQL = mySQL + " From " + dbTables[dbTable] + " WHERE " + strField + " = " + strSearch; //Adds the last part of the sayntex
                break;
            default:
                mySQL = mySQL + " From " + dbTables[dbTable] + " ORDER BY ContractNumber"; //Adds the last part of the sayntex 
                break;
        }

        ConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + strDBPath + ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="; //Selects the database along with the provider of the database

        try 
        {

            using(OleDbConnection MyConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr) )
            {
                MyConn.Open(); //opens MyConn 
                OleDbCommand Cmd = new OleDbCommand(mySQL, MyConn);
                OleDbDataReader ObjReader = Cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (!ObjReader.HasRows)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No rows found"); 
                }
                else
                {
                    while (ObjReader.Read())
                    {
                        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(ObjReader[dbFields[0].ToString()].ToString());
                        for (int i = 1; i < dbFields.Length; i++) //Check to see if last field in array
                            item.SubItems.Add(ObjReader[dbFields[i]].ToString());
                        lstContracts.Items.Add(item);
                    }  
                }
                dbSearch = true;
                ObjReader.Close();
                Cmd.Dispose();
                MyConn.Close();
            } 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            oErrorLog.WriteErrorLog(ex.ToString());
            dbSearch = true;
        }
        finally
        {
            dbSearch = true;
        }
    }
```

It's probably something silly but any advise could help.

Comment: Your `dbSearch` variable & loop is extremely wrong.

Comment: what exception r u getting and while debugging where the error is showing.

Comment: The code trips up on 
    OleDbDataReader ObjReader = Cmd.ExecuteReader();

Comment: The error displayed is 
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E07): Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)

Comment: The dbSearch loop was just to make sure that the dbGetdata had been executed before moving to the next table. As thought that may be the cause.